# Retrieving only user names from user details stored in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a login activity in Android studio and for the same, I need to retrieve the list of artist names stored in firebase, in a string one at a time, so that I can perform authentication.How can that be done?
I am new to firebase. please help.

This is my model class

```
public class Artist {

String artistId;
String artistName;
String artistGenre;

public Artist(){}

public Artist(String artistName, String artistId, String artistGenre) {
    this.artistName = artistName;
    this.artistId = artistId;
    this.artistGenre = artistGenre;
}

public String getArtistId() {
    return artistId;
}



public String getArtistName() {
    return artistName;
}


public String getArtistGenre() {
    return artistGenre;
}

}
```

I have attached the database structure image

[Structure of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAKF2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below the code for the retrieve your data(Artist node) from firebase.

```
 public void getAllUsersFromFirebase() {
    DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("artists");
    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            List<Artist > artistUsers = new ArrayList<>();
            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                Artist  artist  = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(Artist.class);
                artistUsers.add(artist);

            }
            mOnGetAllUsersListener.onGetAllUsersSuccess(artistUsers);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mOnGetAllUsersListener.onGetAllUsersFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this**

```
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String Name = String.valueOf(data.child("artistName").getValue());
    list.add(Name);
```

}